# Reuse a custom UITableView in different UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, code-reuse

I'm developing an iPhone app for iOS 5.1. I built a UIViewController which has a UITableView with a UISearchDisplayController and other views, all somehow related to the table. The UIVIewController is the delegate and the datasource of the table, and makes some customizations (graphical and business-related) to the table and search display controller. So far, everything was OK.

The problem is that now I want to put this same table (maybe with a different sublist of elements, of the same type) in different controllers (different screens of the app). I tried to add the tableView of my controller as a subview in other controllers, but it doesn't work. I tried to rebuild my table as a subclass of UIView (instead of UIViewController) and add it as a subview, but it neither worked (it loaded the view from a NIB file, but all its properties, including the IBOutlets, where nil or 0x000000).

After searching a lot, I didn't find any example of how to reuse a tableview in different controllers. Any hint? Any example? Should I build it as a UIViewController or as a UIView? Which class should be the delegate of the table and searchdisplay, keeping in mind that most of the logic I want to reuse is the code in the delegates?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: I have created one BaseTableViewController-subclass of UIViewController. Then I subclass this BaseTableViewController wherever I want that tableview to be displayed. BaseTableViewController defines methods like numberOfSectionsInTableView:, numberOfRowsInSection: & cellForRowAtIndexPath & so on. Also Search functionality is defined in this BaseTableVC, that in turn overrides these methods as per requirement. This all work fine for me

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But, what if I want to place that table as a subview of a complex UIViewController, whose view is built with Interface Builder? Let's say, a view with other labels, imageviews, whatever... My question is, can I build both the reusable table and the views that use it with IB? How can I add the other elements? Thank you

Comment: This is what i could suggest. Try this & let all know the results. In ur complex UIViewController, u can [urUIVC addSubView:BaseTableViewController.view]. Also add other views in this urUIVC as per requirement with GOOD CARE OF FRAME SIZE & POSTION OF VIEWS IN WINDOW. Now urUIVC is with reusable table & the views. In VC file CORRESPONDING  TO .XIB FILE, u can addSubView: urUIVC (comprising of reusable tableview & other views).

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well. Following your recommendation, that complex UIViewController (let's call it ComplexViewController) is the subclass of the BaseTableViewController. But that subclass will contain other views that the table. And BaseTableViewController is built with IB, and I want ComplexViewController visual aspect to be designed with IB as well.

Comment: This view subclassing I suggested previously: UIViewController -> BaseTableViewController -> SampleView1 (will hv reusable table & additional views of ur choice). Now in ComplexViewController, [ComplexViewController addSubView:BaseTableViewController.view] or SampleView] (depends on requirement). U can subclass BaseTableViewController to many SampleViews like SampleView2,3,.. &if u [ComplexViewController adSubView:SampleView1.view] (or SampleView2,view,..) then u'll have ComplexViewController with reusable tableview & other view

Comment: So I load my baseTableViewController from nib (initWithNibName:), and then addSubView:baseTableViewController? Will that way the lifecycle methods on BaseTableViewController (viewDidLoad:, etc) be called?

Comment: No.. Ur SampleView1,2,.. will be .xib files with corresponding .h &.m files which will contain viewDidLoad: methods & all.. Let explain what i did in my project. In AppDelegate file. i hv declared UITabBarController -> UINavigationController1,2.. initWithRootViewController:SampleView1,2.. Got it.

Comment: Quite complex... I set the solution proposed by @zero0cool as the solution because it is much simpler and fully MVC complaint. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the easiest solution be to create your own Datasource class (maybe as a singleton) and then reuse this with the other controller? This way, your way of getting and managing the data is abstracted from the way of displaying it. Just the way it should be. 
This is what MVC is all about.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I'm too newbie on iOS and Objective C. So, can I have a, let's say, third class (subclass of just NSObject) and hook it as table delegate, datasource, and searchdisplaycontroller delegate of multiple tables and search display controllers on multiple views? Is that possible? How could I access it from the UIViewController subclass that uses the table. Should it be a property in the controller? (I've always seen examples where UIViewControllers' subclasses where delegates and datasources, sorry again if I'm asking trivial things...)

Comment: Essentially yes. I understood your problem to be to reuse the same table in another view controller, but what I would suggest is to re-use the same data that makes up the table. This data resides in the datasource instance, which is a delegate (i.e. you delegate the sourcing of the data that makes up the table to some other class you write, most likely a subclass of NSObject). I suggest you read this: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAPIOverview/TableViewAPIOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH4-SW2)

Comment: Thank you @zero0cool, I've done it! Now I have a *Util class which acts as table's datasource and delegate, and another one that acts as delegate of SearchDisplayController. Anywhere I want to reutilice it, I just have to instantiate my Helper and set it as table's and searchDisplayController's delegate and datasource. Thank you!!